# Why does this NServiceBus message handler throw System.MethodAccessException on call to Task.CompletedTask?

Tags: azure, nservicebus

After looking through the documentation and trying to find other examples of developers getting this error, I am a bit stuck.  We are working with NServiceBus 6 and are occasionally getting a `System.MethodAccessException` in our message handlers on the call to `return Task.CompletedTask`.  It seems to only occur when the handler is deployed in an Azure Worker Role (as opposed to running in the emulator).  We are using the Azure Service Bus transport.

```
  public Task Handle(UpdatePatientAccommodationCode message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Handling [{message.GetType()}]");
        var patientVisit = LoadByExternalPatientId(message.ClientId, message.ExternalPatientId);

        var mappedEvent = patientVisit.HandleCommand(message);

        if (patientVisit.IsEventAdded)
            PatientVisitEventStore.Save(patientVisit);

        return mappedEvent == null ? Task.CompletedTask : context.Publish(mappedEvent);
    }
```

The actual exception looks like this:

```
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'XXX.Handlers.PatientVisitHandler.Handle(XXX.UpdatePatientAccommodationCode, NServiceBus.IMessageHandlerContext)' to access method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.get_CompletedTask()' failed.
at XXX.Handlers.PatientVisitHandler.Handle(UpdatePatientAccomm     odationCode message, IMessageHandlerContext context) in PatientVisitHandler.cs:  line 314
at NServiceBus.InvokeHandlerTerminator.Terminate(IInvokeHandlerContext context)       in   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\Invok  eHandlerTerminator.cs: line 24
at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() in     C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\LoadH   andlersConnector.cs: line 40
```

Comment: What version of .NET framework your worker role is using?

Comment: Everything is 4.6.1.  I see your answer below and will verify the Cloud Service version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your code locally has .NET framework 4.6.x which supports `Task.CompletedTask`. When you deploy to CS and use [OS family](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix) less than version 5 won't have support for 4.6.x You either will need to use a startup task to install 4.6.x or migrate to [OS Family 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix#family-5-releases) (Server 2016).

Comment: You are correct in pointing out that the cloud service is definitely an older version.  Once I can get our deployment scripts set up to ensure that we are using the correct OS Family, and verify, I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is strange. Judging by the reference sources of [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1656) I can't come up with a scenario where this could happen. The task that is statically cached is initialized with [`RAN_TO_COMPLETION`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,328) and `DO_NOT_DISPOSE`. Based on that I would suggest you determine whether you are using the .NET Framework version 4.6 or higher. If you do and you still see the exception try to replace `Task.CompletedTask` with

```
static class TaskEx
{
   public static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.FromResult(0); 
}
```